# Does wolf companion reduce the power of Mindless's assault flipped cards in half?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

The interaction between these two cards is unclear. Mindless Assault reads:

> You may choose to flip 1 or more of your Deployed cards at this Location face down: each of your face down Deployed cards at this Location has 4 Power.

The card is activated during the "Preparation" phase of resolution.

Wolf Companion reads:

> The *printed* Power value on each of your Rival's Deployed cards at this Location is halved (rounded down).

The card is activated during the "Conflict" phase of resolution (after Mindless Assault).

Does Wolf Companion reduce the Power of flipped cards down to 2 (from 4)? Or because the Power isn't what's *printed* on the card Mindless Assault's value of 4 is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wolf Companion* only effects the values **printed** on the cards, which means face down cards given 4 power by *Mindless Assault* will not be effected.

This has been somewhat clarified by a *Horrible Guild* post on [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2554418/article/36453515#36453515).